# How can I hide a line and some following, depending a tick box with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been creating a small script to hide rows depending a tick box.
If the tick box is "true", I want to hide it, but the point is that I also want to hide all the next lines between this tick box and the next one.

my spreadsheet is looking like that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDfEh.jpg)

and the code I did so far and who is hidding only the first line (the one with the tick box) is looking like this :

```
function HIDE_OVER_PROJ() {
  

  var REA_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST_PROJETS");



  var over = REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 3, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(over)
  for (let i = 0; i < over.length; i++) {
    if (over[i][0] == (true)) {
      REA_PROJsheet.hideRows([i + 2]);
      }
  }

}
```

what can I do to mask the other lines between the 2 tick box, knowing that sometimes there is 10lines, sometimes only 2, some other times 7...
thanks

Comment: `knowing that sometimes there is 10lines, sometimes only 2, some other times 7` Would you please explain this. Would you also please edit your question to include an example of a successful outcome for each of 2, 7 and 10 lines between checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you need, you must also add a trigger, so that every time you edit the column the function is executed.

```js
function HIDE_OVER_PROJ() {
  var REA_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST_PROJETS");
  var over = REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 3, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();

  var startRow = -1;
  var hideRows = false;

  REA_PROJsheet.showRows(2, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow() - 1);

  for (let i = 0; i < over.length; i++) {
    if (over[i][0] === true) {
      if (!hideRows) {
        startRow = i + 2;
      }
      hideRows = true;
    } else if (over[i][0] === false && hideRows) {
      if (startRow !== -1) {
        REA_PROJsheet.hideRows(startRow, i - startRow + 1);
      }
      startRow = -1;
      hideRows = false;
    }

    if (hideRows && over[i][0] === "") {
      REA_PROJsheet.hideRows(i + 2);
    }
  }

  if (startRow !== -1) {
    REA_PROJsheet.hideRows(startRow, over.length - startRow + 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please show a snapshot of how this handles a variable number of rows.

Comment: Apply the following logic, the function will traverse the column and when it finds a true value, it starts hiding rows from that position until it finds a false value. @Tedinoz